# How to SELECT Column, * FROM TABLE in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a lot of scripts, and sometimes to check that the tables are being updated as I need, I write on the fly several SELECT statements.

In SQL SERVER you can write something like:

```
SELECT Column1, *
FROM MY_TABLE
```

This is useful for visibility reasons, however that doesn't seem to work in ORACLE and I don't know how to achieve it, other than writing down all the Column Names manually.

**How can you do this in oracle?**

I know we shouldn't include a query like this in our production scripts, etc. I am just trying to use it on the fly while I am running my scripts in development. At different points I'm more interested to see the information of certain columns, in relation to the other ones, but I still want to see all the columns.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
SELECT Column1, MY_TABLE.*
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Or if you give the table an alias:

```
SELECT Column1, T.*
FROM MY_TABLE T
```

Comment: That was rather simple! I feel dumb for not having found it before. Thank!

Comment: It is actually not obvious at first select a,* from table works almost every where except oracle.

Comment: Everything normal works almost everywhere else except oracle.

Answer (score 10):

Use an alias:

```
SELECT Column1, t.*
FROM MY_TABLE t;
```