# Analytic function throwing error in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am writing a very simple rank function to calculate the rank for each group by partitioning on some specific columns. The sql looks straightforward for me but I really dont understand why I am getting ORA error. Please find my sql and error as below. Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks.

**`SQL :-`**

```
 SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY STUDENTID,BOOKISBN ORDER BY ISSUEDATE )  "RN"
   FROM BORROWED_BY;
```

**`Error:-`**

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SELECT Column, \* FROM TABLE in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965130/how-to-select-column-from-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `SELECT *` with other columns, you need to qualify it:

```
SELECT bb.*,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENTID, BOOKISBN ORDER BY ISSUEDATE ) as RN
FROM BORROWED_BY bb;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!